# Editing SharePoint Page

Tags: edit

I was asked today to edit some text on one of our SharePoint page, when I asked for the URL they send me the following URL which ends like this `_layouts/15/Prg.SP13.EmployeeXtras.Core/EmployeeXtras.aspx`

The issue is I can't see any edit option or any other SharePoint options in this page, can you please help?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is application page and it cannot be edited via UI. Looking at the URL you provided and folder structure it seems this is custom application page deployed via Farm solution(WSP). To modify this page you need to update your code base.... Whatever changes you need to make it has to be done in wsp and then wsp needs to be redeployed.

Comment: Thanks for your message Siddharth, i have checked the farm solution and i cant see any solution related to this page

Comment: Prg.SP13.EmployeeXtras.Core this should be your solution namespace....it is definitely coming from wsp, check central admin farm solution gallery with similar name

Comment: you were right, that is the wsp file solution, and thanks for that, but surely, every time you want to edit some text on the page you don't need to update the .wsp file.there should be other ways to simply edit the page.

Comment: It is design flaw in your solution...ideally, what we do is keep a list to store the labels/configurable text and assign it to page dynamically.....if it is simple aspx page text change you can always edit it and copy page in all your servers(NOT RECOMMENDED) but it could be one way...

Comment: thanks again for your messages, but where is this page? is there any way i can edit this page without editing WSP file?

Comment: It would in 15 hive folder following same path as in your url

Comment: please see the screenshot, i cant see it in the 15 hive folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97407/discussion-between-siddharth-vaghasia-and-harris).